# $f,g$ cont. functions on $[a,b]$ and $g$ is non-negative. then $\exists c \in [a,b]$ such that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) dx = f(c) \int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

let $f,g$ be continuous functions on $[a,b]$ and suppose that $g$ is non-negative. then there exists apoint $c \in [a,b]$ such that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) dx = f(c) \int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx.$

I have seen a solution similar to my problem in the link below, except that this solution assumes that $g>0,$ but my problem assumes that $g \geq 0$, does my problem contain a mistake? or the result is true also if g is non negative?

[Existence of $c$ such that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x)dx = f(c)\int_{a}^{b} g(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2932152/existence-of-c-such-that-int-ab-fxgxdx-fc-int-ab-gx)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1755859/42969. Your concerns are addressed in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1068597/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1755889/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g\equiv 0$ then you can take any $c$. Otherwise $\int_a^{b} g(x)dx>0$ and that is enough for the proof you have seen. In that proof the only that could cause problem is division by $\int_a^{b} g(x)dx$].